# Streaming audio w/ metadata causes browsers to stop

Tags: html, audio, stream, ogg, icecast

We have an ogg vorbis stream from an icecast2 server. When the metadata is enabled within the stream, the stream will stop playing (though still connected to the server) when a new logical stream is started (when the metadata changes) within chrome and firefox using the native html5  tag. However, this does not happen when the metadata is disabled from the audio stream.

```
<p><b>Example of audio tag in HTML5.</b></p>
<audio src="http://mysite:port/stream.ogg" controls ></audio>
```

We need the metadata in the stream so we can't disable it. Does anyone know a work around for this? Any insight would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Icecast should only include the metadata when requested, which a browser won't do.  Can you fire up Wireshark, and do a packet capture for this?  I want to verify that Icecast is sending metadata despite the fact that the header to request it isn't present.  If it is, it's a bug in your particular version of Icecast.

Comment: Having the same problem with a streams served up both from Ices and SAM broadcaster.  Were you able to solve this?  Is there a metadata format that won't clog up the browser?

Comment: @Dmitri Hmm haven't thought about changing the metadata format but I don't think that will solve it as this issue is a known bug within Mozilla. One thing that may work is to use javascript or php to filter the metadata out in specific pages.

Comment: Thanks!  I think it must be a bug in Chrome as well, because it does the same thing; streaming with the metadata stripped out of the tracks didn't help either; the only way I got an ogg stream to work is if it was generated by SAM broadcaster and didn't include the metadata. Ices2 and Liquidsoap streams stopped on each track even with stripped ogg files.  I'm still trying to figure this out.